# AWS Glue Crawler issue

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a requirement for a ETL process where Raw data will be loaded into s3 buckt every day 1 time(Zip may contain 30 to 50 individual files with different schema). The data will be new every day and may or may not have same schema. I have unzipped teh data and loaded into 1 s3 bucket and crawled the files and run some jobs an processed the data. Now the problem is next day when new raw data is loaded and when I crawl teh newly updated folder again, tables remain the same in Glue catalog with same data reference.

What alternate option do I have if teh daya changes daily and new tables should be created the next day. or how can I read only the new data.??

I tried to crawl new folders with same crawler and same DB with different s3 folder.

Comment: Are you able to query the data from these new raw data?

Comment: I changed the data source of the crawler to new folders and then crawled again. that will again create new tables which will refer to new data. I want to know if this can be done dynamically for every crawl as RAW data will be loaded on a daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the schema of the new raw files is same as the ones on which the Crawler already crawled. You will not see new table creation in this case. That's how it Crawler works.

To confirm this, Query the files using Athena by selecting the table that crawler created, you should be able to see all the data from all the files.

New tables will only be created if the schema of these new files is different.

To understand how Crawler works, give [this doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-crawler-detect-schema/) a go.

Comment: Thank you @Rishabh Sahrawat for your valuable answer. For the scenario where multiple CSV files will be loaded to s3 on a daily basis with different data but the same schema and same Transformation, what is the ideal approach.??

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you are receiving data with same schema and transformation then you just run the crawler first time. You can also run it everyday but it would not add more tables, so it will be kind of waste.

Comment: Thank you Rishabh Sahrawat, I got a complete idea of how the crawler works. My issue is with the recurring CSV files that are loaded into the s3 bucket in different folders daily. the folder structure will be like                                                                                      [Raw_data] -[main files-30 CSV] +[reference files-20 CSV files]